# My search bar won't show anything in list

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, mobile

I have a view model for country codes, names, flags...

How can I search through that list once I fetch it?

My search code is like this:

```
   ForEach(countryVM.diallingCode.filter{$0.name.lowercased()
   .contains(self.textlowercased())}, id:\.self) { option in
                VStack{
                    Divider()
                        .frame(maxWidth:.infinity)

                    HStack{
                        Image(option.flag)
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width:30, height:30)
                        Text(option.name)
                            .font(.custom("Ubuntu-Light", size:12))
                        Spacer()
                    }.frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
                }
            }
```

There is array in diallingCode, it shows me the countries, but I can't search through them.

The same code worked when I used static values.

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
 including the view model and how you declare it.

Comment: Try print out what `countryVM.diallingCode.filter{$0.name.lowercased().contains(self.textlowercased())}` produces

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier on yourself, move

```
countryVM.diallingCode.filter{$0.name.lowercased().contains(self.textlowercased())}`
```

to a method on your view model, e.g.

```
func filteredDialingCodes(for text: String) {
    let codes = diallingCode.filter{$0.name.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())}
    print(codes) // see what's happening
    return codes
}
```

Then call like:

```
ForEach(filteredDialingCodes(for: text), id:\.self) { option in
```

Not only is it clearer what you're trying to do, it also will allow you to see what values are returned when filtering.